# How to make subtitle text appear over the video?

Tags: subtitles

1) I have an English movie and its .srt subtitle file (both downloaded from internet).

2) I have another movie (which I am part of) for which I have made the subtitles using "Subtitle Edit" software (version 3.5.8). Format: .srt; encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)

I use VLC media player to watch both the films.

Now, when I play the English film, the subtitles (both the lines) appear inside the bottom edge of the screen (I mean the text is over the video).

But, when I play my movie, the subtitle text is pushed down right below the video in the black area.
This may become a problem when this film will be played on big screens in film festivals if the subtitles are not displayed at all. So my director wants the subtitle text to appear over the video at the bottom center.

How to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Also, I don't understand why despite both being .srt files, all else unchanged their behavior is different while played in vlc.

Answer (score 0):

There can be just video quality issues, when you watch Hollywood movie that may be corner to corner aligned and your film may have black strips on up and down.

No big deal in that your subtitles also appear when you play on big screen, try it. By the way you don't have other options.